# Split a column in a table which is in JSON format in to multiple column using SQL server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2012, json.net

There is one specific column which holds data in JSON format, i need help in splitting the single column in to multiple column as given below,

Column value in a table: ('{"Date":"31.12.2020","Value":208983916.71000000000}')

Expected output:

Date         Value

31.12.2020  208983916.7

Comment: Any reason for tagging `json.net`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON_VALUE` for this

```sql
SELECT
    Date =  JSON_VALUE(t.YourCol, '$.Date'),
    Value = JSON_VALUE(t.YourCol, '$.Value')
FROM YourTable t;
```

Alternatively, you can use `OPENJSON` (more useful if you have many columns)

```sql
SELECT
    j.Date,
    j.Value
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.YourCol)
  WITH ( Date varchar(20), Value decimal(20,11) ) AS j;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :)